# Microsoft MSMQ on Windows Server 2008 over HTTPS

Tags: https, dns, ssl-certificate, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

We are trying to get MSMQ working over HTTPS.  Messages sent over the internet to an Windows 2008 R2 server sitting on the cloud at rackspace works correctly when sent via HTTP.  We have a certificate created for our domain and can access the web server via http and https with no problems.  We are trying to use the same certificate for MSMQ, but it does not work.  This is the explanation from Microsoft in their documentation, and is exactly what we experience.  When we use http, it works, but when we use https, then we get an error in the event log that the certificate does not match the name of the destination. Messages then sent via https accumulates in the outgoing queue.

The full article is here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736680%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

"A server certificate obtained from a CA can be issued to the NetBIOS name or full DNS name of a computer. However, when HTTPS messages are sent, the destination specified in messages must be identical to the computer name in the recipient's server certificate. Thus, when only the NetBIOS name of the destination (for example, with a direct format name of the form DIRECT=$/q1) is used to send messages within the same forest over an intranet to a computer whose server certificate contains the full DNS name, authentication fails. Consequently, when Message Queuing tries to create an SSL session, it receives a warning that the name in the certificate does not match the name of the destination, and the messages sent in this way accumulate in the outgoing queue."

Our server name and Netbios name is different from the DNS name that points the IP Address to our website domain.  We tried to change the computer name to be the same as our website domain to get it to correspond with the certificate domain address, but it does not work as periods are not allowed in the server name.

Any help will be appreciated.

Please assist